# How I can change class in messages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to replace magento default alerts to bootstrap alerts.

I try add template for messages in design/frontend/templates/messages.phtml. Buy I cannot change class of type message from message-error to message-danger.

How I can change message class in all system in frontend?

Comment: This is an interesting question from the technical point of view, but to solve your problem, why not apply the styles you have on `message-danger` to the class `message-error`? Wouldn't it be easier?

Comment: Once a client asked to add close button to message in Magento 1.9. I used jquery to dynamically add bootstrap close button (alert message ). May be you can try this way

Comment: @Marius That's why http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-examples

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but I think the frontend messages are rendered by this template `https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html`.
You can create this file in your theme and replace `message-error` with `message-danger`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
class: 'alert-' + (message.type == 'success' ? message.type : 'danger') + ' alert'
```

Problem with `MessageInterface::TYPE_ERROR`. Magento use this interface in "100" places (that's why I cannot redefine classes). And I cannot redefine the interface.